# Как из Java считать информацию с pdb

Tags: java, python

Доброе время суток.
Есть желание написать дебагер питона, который получает информацию, возвращаемую от вызова скрипта через pdb.
Допустим, есть скрипт в файлике test.py, который лежит в папке проекта.
Вот код main функции.

```
    Process p;
    String line;
    ProcessBuilder builder = new ProcessBuilder("python", "-m", "pdb", "test.py");
    builder.directory(new File(System.getProperty("user.dir")));
    try {
        p = builder.start();
        BufferedReader bfr = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
        line = bfr.readLine();
        System.out.println(line);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Во время выполнения программы ничего не происходит. На строке bfr.readLine() программа ожидает ввода. Если же "python -m pdb test.py" запустить в консоли то он выводит

```
i:\pythondebugger\test.py(7)<module>()
-> import pdb
```

Когда я запускаю программу без pdb, т.е заменяю на new ProcessBuilder("python", "test.py"), то readLine считывает информацию, которую выводит скрипт.
Как сделать так, чтобы программа считывала информацию, выводимую pdb?